# How to use grid system without bootstrap

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to handle my homework, where I got asked to create a responsive grid (using media queries) which contains UP to 4 columns (column minimal width is 300 pixels)
and I'm not allowed to use any library.

I have tried to look at bootstrap grid system and to apply it on my code but it did not go so well for me.
I have issues with the part of the minimum width of each column and the fact that it needs to contain up to 4 columns...

maybe I did not understand the requirements of the question so well...

Comment: You can use [CSS Columns](https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/), you can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or you can use [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: after reading the flexbox tutorial (bootstrap4 is based on flex), make a try and come back with your code to show your issues ;) here is also an article about mediaqueries https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 7):

This is a basic grid layout I've created for you. It starts off being 4 columns wide on 992px wide screens and then shrinks down to 3, 2 and 1 column as the screen gets smaller. The widths of the columns can be easily changed to match your specifications and then you can obviously just change the media query break points too.

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

.container .col {
  background: lightblue;
}

.container .col p {
  padding: .25rem .75rem;
}


/* 2 columns (600px) */

@media only screen and (min-width:600px) {
  .container .col {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* 3 columns (768px) */

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .container .col {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
}


/* 4 columns (992px) */

@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .container .col {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores sequi sint ipsa alias amet. Numquam voluptatum maiores. Ab repellat dolores quo quas quam quasi voluptatem delectus aperiam. Deleniti accusamus dolore!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores sequi sint ipsa alias amet. Numquam voluptatum maiores. Ab repellat dolores quo quas quam quasi voluptatem delectus aperiam. Deleniti accusamus dolore!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores sequi sint ipsa alias amet. Numquam voluptatum maiores. Ab repellat dolores quo quas quam quasi voluptatem delectus aperiam. Deleniti accusamus dolore!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores sequi sint ipsa alias amet. Numquam voluptatum maiores. Ab repellat dolores quo quas quam quasi voluptatem delectus aperiam. Deleniti accusamus dolore!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w5hjod0q/1/

Comment: its about homework without library, i guess plain HTML & CSS is the idea , sass will confuse the op imho ;) The op doesn't seem to be a css expert to handle sass yet

Comment: Fair point :) I've changed my answer to reflect this and added the plain CSS

Comment: it looks great - but i got one more question - when im making the size smaller, there are parts where the divs are not breaking(to be 3, 2 and so on,,,), instead the screen just overwrites them.
how can i fix it so it will always be full divs and not half - and break

Comment: @Àtishking Please see my edited post. the `container` had a fixed width on originally, I changed this by adding break points.

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 Thank you very much.

Comment: @Àtishking No problem, please consider marking the answer as correct if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally never used Bootstrap, but I have used `display: grid;` in CSS.
The was this works is by telling the parent element to display the child elements in a grid, the way you can specify how many is by using the `display: grid;` in combination with `grid-template-columns`. This CSS property declares how many elements to display in a row and what proportion they should be relative to each other.
for example:

```
  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr, 2fr, 1fr;
  }
```

This will display three elements per row with the center one being twice the size as the outer ones.
a full and working example is provide below.

```css
@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  #wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  }
}
@media (max-width:1279px) {
  #wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
}
p:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: lightgrey;
}
/*
You can of course add @media queries to make sure they work on every screen
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you need a lot of elements on the same line with the same width you can also use the `repeat(n, size)` value, this does the same as writing Nfr multiple times, but it's a lot cleaner.